# Again, my plots are not displaying

Tags: plotting

I am very new to *Mathematica* and I am having an issue with plots not displaying. i am using *Mathematica* 10 student edition. As per a previous post, I restarted the kernel, but that didn't seem to help.

```
{x, y, z} = Range[3];
f[x_, y_] := y^2 - 2 x + 4 sin (3 x + 2 y);
G1 = 
  Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 20}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, PlotRange -> {-5, 20}]
```

only displays an empty box.

```
C1 = ParametricPlot3D[{x, 1, f[x, 2]}, {x, -2, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

also displays an empty box and there are others, but

```
TLine = 
   ParametricPlot3D[{2, 1, 4 Cos[8] - 3} + t {2, 1, 2 + Cos[8]}, 
     {t, -2, 2}, 
     AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

displays correctly. Is there a command im not using or not using incorrectly?

Comment: Please do not label questions about plotting with the tag [tag:graphs-and-networks]. That tag is reserved for questions concerning graph theory. In the _Mathematica_ world, what you think of a graphs are called plots (and the functions provided all have `Plot` in their name) to distinguish them from graphs which are nodes connected by lines (i.e., networks).

Comment: Also, see [Why do I get an empty plot?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88571/8253)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double-check your syntax: `sin` needs to be `Sin` and the parentheses need to be square brackets in your definition of `f`. You don't need the first line (`{x, y, z} = Range[3];`).

The notebook interface has color coding which can help avoid errors like these. Defined symbols (`Sin`) are black, while undefined symbols are blue (`sin`), although you perhaps had `sin` defined elsewhere.

Comment: @m_goldberg Intended to comment the question?

Comment: @IPoiler. Right. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: @m_goldberg Sorry. Didn't mean to seem pedantic, just wanted to make sure the intended inbox got the delivery.

Comment: @IPoiler. Wasn't being sarcastic. Really glad you pointed it out. I moved the comment to where it really should go.